# Tratando Resposta JSON com Retrofit em Android Studio

Tags: java, json, string, android-studio, retrofit

Pra ser bem claro estou desenvolvendo um teste de aplicativo simples, onde o meu usuário digita o cpf de um cliente cadastrado e seus dados como clientes aparecem na tela.
O meu servidor me retorna um json com uma estrutura simples assim:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Lucas","cpf":11111111100,"tel1":33999999999,"empresa":"Empresa 1"}
```

Utilizando retrofit eu faço a chamada normalmente

```
@GET("{id}")
Call<Cliente> getCliente(@Path("id")  String  cliente);
public static final  Retrofit retrofit=  new
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://meuIP:porta/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Crio um POJO para receber os dados do json:

```
public class Cliente{

int id;
public String name;
public String cpf;
public String tel1;
public String empresa;

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}
```

e na minha classe principal eu faço a chamada atravez de um click num botão:

```
btLogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Aqui a função do botão entrar

            RetrofitDados  retrofitDados = RetrofitDados.retrofit.create(RetrofitDados.class);
            final Call<Cliente> call = retrofitDados.getCliente("");


            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Cliente> call, Response<Cliente> response) {

                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    int code = response.code();
                    //boolean resposta = response.isSuccessful();

                    if (code == 200) {
                        Cliente cliente = response.body();

                        verificarCpf(cliente.cpf);

                    } else {
                        gerarToast("Falha:  " + String.valueOf(code));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Cliente> call, Throwable t) {
                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Funciona perfeitamente ate ai.
Quando faço a verificação dos dados retornados (no caso o cpf do cliente digitado) o programa nao faz a verificação e nao me retonra um erro.

Na minha interface existe um TextInputLayout com um TextInputEditText onde eu digito o cpf do cliente .
O programa deveria verificar a "igualdade" entre o que foi digitado e a resposta do servidor.

```
private void verificarCpf(final String cpf) {

    String resposta = textCPF.getText().toString();

    if ( resposta == cpf) {
        gerarToast("" + cpf);
    } else {
        Log.e("TAG", resposta);
    }

}
```

mesmo a minha resposta convertida em String

```
cliente.cpf
```

e o meu EditText convertido em String

```
textCPF.getText().toString();
```

tendo o mesmo valor de resultado. Não ha verificação.

E o que eu gostaria é de uma dica e uma solução, caso eu esteja esquecendo de fazer alguma coisa no código.

Comment: Essa comparação ´ if ( resposta == cpf)´ esta errada. Dessa maneira você esta comparando o objeto resposta com o objeto cpf e eles não são iguais. Você deve comparar assim: ´ if ( resposta.equals(cpf)) ´

Comment: eu sabia que tava esquecendo de algo... MUITO OBRIGADO